# Camera not Following To Bezier Curve

Tags: bezier-curves

I am trying to get a Camera (or Empty) to follow a 3d Bezier curve on a Mars landscape, it follows a 3d path while tracking a Mars rover which successfully follows a nurbspath (I changed as couldnt seem to get it working a second time either). I think it is something to do with my world origin ? maybe ? I am using Blender 3.1.2, answer to similar issues dont seem to have the same result (when translating from older versions)

Here is my viewport
[image]
And when I either Add a "follow To" constraint or parent a "follow to" of the empty (or camera) to the Bezier curve. It jumps away, far away
[image]

Now Ive set the origin cursor at the origin of cube, start of curve and camera, and "Shift-S" / Cursor to World Origin

And right clicked on the curve to select "Set Origin" "Origin to 3d cursor"

But again same thing

My terrian is at altitude but dont think thats the issue - any ideas anyone ?

TIA yap

Comment: Position Camera at Curve start, add Constraint > Follow Path, Target > Bezier Curve, Forward Axis Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome, You've got a few things going on in your setup that are creating problems.

Start by hiding everything that isn't connected to the camera movement.

[image]
You've got an errant Keyframe leftover from a previous 'Follow Path' Constraint on the camera. Select the camera and delete that in the Timeline.

[image]
If you open the Output Properties tab, you've changed the Time Stretching values. Reset these both to 100.

[image]
Select the Bezier Curve / Path and open the Object Data Properties Tab. Under Path Animation change the Frames value to 1000 to match what you've set as the clip length in the Timeline. You might also want to select Clamp to restrict the movement to the end points of your path.

[image]
Now add your 'Follow Path' Object Constraint to the camera, and set the target to Bezier Curve. Drag it above the Track constraint in the stack. Reset the location values of the Camera to 0 and it will locate the camera at the beginning of your curve/path.

[image]
You might also want to change the Frame count for your Nurbs Path under the Path Animation settings.

[image]
Notice that the Offset Value in the settings for your Follow Path constraint correspond to frame number and if you click and drag the value it will move the camera along the path.

Press Shift + L-Arrow to set the Timeline at Frame 1.

Set this Offset value to -1000. Keyframe it by pressing the button to the right of the Offset Value, this will change into a diamond shape.

Press Shift + R-Arrow to set the Timeline at the last frame (Frame 1000). Change the Offset value to 1000. And Keyframe it.

It should work now.

Alternatively, you can add the Follow Path constraint to your Empty Cube, and either Parent your Camera to the Empty or add a 'Child Of' constraint to the camera and target it to the Empty.

Hope that helps, if you find it's still not working, it should be one of those various settings that needs adjusting to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Find the right direction from which your Camera starts following the curve and then edit your curve to make desired shape

Follow screenshots and remake your `BezieCurve` from scratch
(In my example the Empty Cube starts following the curve from it's end)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Note: Before setting up all constraints, make a quick test to know from which direction your Camera starts following the curve, if it's the wrong one, edit the Curve

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer kempleart, and thats exactly what i did but the empty never follows the curve. It sort of does in a weird chaotic fashion, sometimes at a distance (not along the path) and sometimes diving under the plane. I have the blend file here https://1drv.ms/u/s!Amv6AWCUsu_YmitRFzSCBTdxmt0L?e=9LEN40 with an empty and Bezier curve on opening, do the above steps you mention and see what happens !

Comment: please only share the curve and camera  ;)

Comment: What is the purpose to parent Camera to EmptyCube?

Comment: @yetanotherpassword try to apply all transforms for the Curve

Comment: @yetanotherpassword I got it working: Apply All Transforms for both `Empty Cube` and the `BezierCurve`. Then parent `Camera` to the `Empty Cube` and add `follow path` modifier